# How to set a fixed baseline that doesn't stretch for ascenders or descenders?

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, line-spacing, baseline, strut

Given many lines of text from a parameter or `\input` file, that contain end-of-line tags, ascenders and descenders:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}

% Some Code <Here> to disable TeX from
% factoring in ascenders and descenders
% in determining `\baselinestretch`

This is an ugly line of texting with "xxx".\\
Yay for descenders hanging with "xxx".\\
And ascenders' apostrophes with "xxx".\\
\end{document}
```

I would like to ***save the "vertical space" that TeX adds when it considers ascenders and descenders, and make those lines as compact as the lines that don't have them***.

How does one make the baselineskip EXACTLY the same between each line, regardless if there are ascenders or descenders?

How does one enable or disable TeX from dynamically adjusting the baseline because of these?

Note, the distance between the bottoms and tops of the "x"s should always be consistent.

The distinction between this and other similar questions is that this is not limited to two lines, or even just one paragraph, (but rather, an entire chapter).

Comment: what you ask for is the default behaviour of tex. Please _always_ provide a complete test file that shows the problem. Perhaps you have some non-standard settings giving you uneven baseline spacing but hard to guess with no information shown.

Comment: baselineskip is the baseline-to-baseline spacing so the actual glue added will vary depending on the height and depth of the characters  to ensure that the space between your `xxx` will be equal (unless the line has something really big that forces the lines apart, an inline 10-row matrix for example...) .  Basically you posted the code above  asking how to make the space between the xxx equal, so it is really your responsibility to provide an example where the spacing is not equal, so people have a question to answer.

Comment: why would you want to disable that? If you do the linespacing will be totally uneven with lines with lowercase closer together than lines with uppercase, do you really want that?

Comment: you have not defined your terms "same baselineskip" would normally be interpreted to mean the same baseline to baseline spacing. and that is what you get by default. The actual glue tex adds is from the bottom of one row to the top of the next, so if they are just rows of `....` the added glue is almost `\baselineskip` as the line boxes have little height but if the rows are `AgAgAg` then to maintain baseline spacing the glue between the bottom of a g and the top of an A needs to be less.

Comment: \baselineskip is designed to precisely fit descenders (\strut).  If you want it to fit \mathstrut, that could probably be done.  OTOH, if you want to save space, use \baselineskip=0pt and revert to \lineskip.

Comment: Whenever the distance between the top of the next line and the bottom of the previous line is less than \lineskiplimit instead of using \baselineskip between baselines it add \lineskip between the lines.

Comment: @elikakohen John is suggesting the setting with `\setlength\baselineskip{0pt}`  which does save space (but makes your text fairly unreadable) If that is really what you want that is how to get it but.....

Comment: your bold text `save the "vertical space" that TeX adds when it considers ascenders and descenders, and make those lines as compact as the lines that don't have them.`  really is not answerable. TeX _reduces_ the space it adds between lines if there are descenders or tall letters. It does not add anything.

Comment: I give up. a fixed distance is the default behaviour.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - \setlength\baselineskip{0pt} did the trick.   I understand that I am using the wrong words....    If you could help with my wording, (knowing that is the answer), I would be very grateful.  Is there any way to add just a little FIXED space back in?

Comment: You might also increase \lineskip from 1pt (default).

Comment: @JohnKormylo - I have no idea how you managed to divine my intention. `\setlength\baselineskip{0pt}\lineskip=4pt {\normalfont\bfseries\libertine\upshape\scshape #1}` Is what I just used... and it works as needed.  I don't really understand it, though.    Can you post your answer for me to accept?

Comment: @elikakohen increase `\lineskip` (but please don't use this setting in an actual document, pity your poor readers)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - It is just in the table of contents, (multi-line chapter names).  The way they were formatting was too inconsistent to be presentable. It isn't in the body - but I totally understand. And thank you for your patience.

Comment: you are forcing them to be inconsistent, the default setting will give even baselines (or your (unshown_ table of contents setup is incorrect.

Comment: Your image clearly shows you're asking an XY-question. Your setting of `\baselineskip` is wrong for that font, which has quite high glyphs.

Comment: @egreg - I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "XY-question". But, yes - the setting is wrong, but at least now I have control over it and can manually move it around through trial and error.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to get superugly output. The distance between baselines is fixed at 2ex, notwithstanding ascenders and descenders.

You'll get clashes, though.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength\baselineskip{2ex}
\setlength\lineskiplimit{-\maxdimen}

\noindent
This is an ugly line of texting with "xxx".\\
Yay for descenders hanging with "xxx".\\
And ascenders' apostrophes with "xxx".

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change “an” in the first line with “ap”, you get

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (with `\baselineskip`), except, according to John's comment, I added `\lineskip` to add whitespace back in (not gluey)...  Could you add that here to show how  you can make it readable afterwards? What is the difference between `\lineskip` and `\lineskiplimit` in this context?

Comment: @elikakohen `\lineskip` is the amount of glue added if the distance between the lines is less than `\lineskiplimit` once ascenders, descenders and the baselineskip are taken into account. Since `\lineskiplimit` is set to the smallest possible dimension, no two lines will be deemed too near to each other, so the distance between baselines will be `\baselineskip` in every case. I'm not sure what you mean by “make it readable afterwards”. Increase the baseline skip, if that's what you mean.

Comment: To "save space" (for printing, presumably?), shrink the font and let the reader zoom in (magnify) unlimited: you could fit a whole chapter on a page, like microfilm readers do. Or an InfoDot. If physical printing is required, "saving space" is not the priority for readability: good font, large size, nice paper, good ink.